# Female F connector diameter

Tags: rf, connector, coax

I am having trouble finding the exact spec for the female F connector- what I need exactly is to know what is the connector diameter and the thread width. I found some info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector), but its not clear to me.

[image]

What I need is the female connector diameter, possibly with and without the thread:

[image]

Should I assume, based on the information from Wikipedia that the female F connector diameter (including the thread) is 9.5 mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An F connector has 3/8 - 32 UNEF threads - the outer diameter of the threaded portion is 3/8".  As this is a North American connector, dimensions are in inches.